# How do I get finder to show the correct 'Kind', after deleting an application?

Tags: macos, finder

When a file for a known application is renamed to a different extension, for example ".notanext", it retains both the icon and the 'kind' listed in the finder window. The icon can be getting rid of by deleting the icon cache (although I really don't get why I should need to).

However, I'm not succeeding getting rid of the 'kind' - it keeps the text of the last 'known' extension. I've tried clearing the launch services database both manually with lsregister as well as with OnyX. I've also cleared all extra attributes with xattr.

I am not looking to know how to register a new application association. I want to deregister a known application completely so the file view in finder reverts to what it would have been in a pristine installation.

I am running Monterey. To reproduce, pick any file with a known application and an icon and a 'kind', then rename it with an extension guaranteed to be unknown on the system. The icon and the 'kind' stays the same. After clearing launch services database. After reboot. At least for me. I don't have access to any other macOS systems to compare with.

So, the question is: How do I get finder to show the correct 'Kind', after deleting an application?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If your problem is solved, you'll find many people here will vote up a question and an answer if you put all the "answer" below and then edit the question not to say solved and be more like a blog post / wiki entry. Accepting your answer also lets people know they don't need to try an answer unless they have a big update or disagree with your answer. Questions may get down votes if there's not a clear question asked - preferably at the end of the question.

Comment: I think you're saying I should rewrite it to be more of an "for information to anyone who cares", like a blog post? It's still an evolving issue, and I was hoping for someone to actually help me out. In the meantime, I continue investigating and keep learning new things. It's an honest question, just not getting any answers so I just keep digging.

Should I rewrite it to be more of a statement than a question, wasn't sure if this was ok?

Comment: No - I'm trying to get a short clear question and then a long detailed answer. Let's start by you answering it with your work so far so we can cut that out of the question. Then if you still have a question it might be more clear what precisely that is...

Comment: So... Edit the question to only contain the actual question, then answer my own question with an "answer" with my findings? It didn't feel right to post an answer to my own question, but sure if that's the normal procedure.

Comment: Yes, this is very much encouraged and by design. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @bmike - Better?

Comment: I think it's excellent. Let's see how others vote. Thank you so much for adapting to the peculiar way we take to our Q & A here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Launch Services is aggressive in adding apps and associations to its database and Finder in adding new stuff. Not quite so much in cleaning it up...

It'll find and use just about anything that is an app, i.e. a folder with a .app ending and the proper structure of an app. Including in the Trash! As a developer, that's fairly annoying. Can't find a way to restrict it to for example '/Applications'. The usual recipes about running lsregister -kill doesn't help, since it'll just rediscover the various apps and re-register in the database. To clean up old entries, delete the offending app from the file system and if it still doesn't go away from Launch Services do something like the following to find the culprit and get rid of it:

```
alias lsregister=/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
lsregister -dump | grep path: | grep -i [AppNameToUnregister]
lsregister -u [ThePathFound].app
killall Finder
```

In general, the -dump option is very useful to understand just what goes in there and to find whatever you want gone from it. Normally an app will be removed from the Launch Services database when it's deleted **and** removed from Trash - but you'll still have to restart Finder to get it to get it too (with `killall Finder` for example).

It's not only Launch Services that's aggressive in collecting and displaying information that it's hard to understand where it comes from. Spotlight indexing... It collects meta data from all kinds of places. The most common recipes for clearing the index turns out not to be the best (mdutil -E to 'clear' the index is most often suggested). Not sure what -E really does, but mdutil -X is better. It really deletes stuff, including legacy and old things. So, something like this:

```
sudo mdutil -d /
sudo mdutil -d /System/Volumes/Data
sudo mdutil -X /
sudo mdutil -X /System/Volumes/Data
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -i on /System/Volumes/Data
```

Some sites claim `/` and `/System/Volumes/Data` refer to the same location, but if you do `mdutil -L` it'll list different contents. So, just to be sure, I delete both. If someone knows better, please comment!

Concerning the icon, I've had success in reseting it with just `sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store` . Many sites also recommend deleting a bunch of other things i `/private/var/folders` and some other actions. It's not been required for me, but perhaps this will cause unreferenced 'garbage' to be left behind. Don't really know. If you do know, please comment!

Finally it appears, although I've not been able to prove this, that Spotlight will actually index and populate the `kMDItemKind` property using file extension associations found from iOS apps on the appstore! You can use `mdls` to display all the Spotlight index properties. This is on macOS. I have tried very hard, including searching every file in the file system for the 'kind' in question, and the only explanation I can find is that Spotlight falls back to app manifests (info.plist) picked up from iOS apps that appear in the store, even on macOS. There's something like trying too hard... If someone can explain the behavior in a different way, please do!

(This is on Monterey with one disk. Your mileage may vary, and probably will, as Apple apparently changes almost everything between each release. But it should still give some useful hints on where to start.)